# Website not rendering properly on next.js for mobile

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, vercel

I downloaded a website template online and I didn't like the implementation to converted to TS and a next project so that it could easily be deployed to Vercel. However, when I put it in mobile mode on Chrome dev tools this happens:
[website picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tcga.png)

The entire website is pushed to the left half of the screen.

This is not a responsive issue because when I shrink the size on normal desktop view it works perfectly

[desktop small screen view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PJce.png)

I have tried setting HTML width to 100% and 100vh and every CSS trick in the book. I am convinced that it is an issue with server-side rendering because there are flashes where the website is rendering properly e.g. after a 500 error it works fine and then after I refresh the page it returns the half view.

**next.config.js::**

```
module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
};
```

**next-env.d.ts:**

```
/// <reference types="next" />
/// <reference types="next/types/global" />
/// <reference types="next/image-types/global" />
```

**_app.tsx:**

```
import type { AppProps } from "next/app";
import "../core/scss/style.scss";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />;
}
export default MyApp;
```

**_document.tsx:**

```
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from "next/document";

class MyDocument extends Document {
  // @ts-ignore
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);
    console.log(initialProps);
    return { ...initialProps };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Html>
        <Head />
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}

export default MyDocument;
```

**package.json:**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@chakra-ui/react": "^1.6.5",
    "@emotion/react": "^11",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.35",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.3",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.14",
    "classnames": "^2.3.1",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "framer-motion": "^4",
    "history": "^5.0.0",
    "next": "11.0.1",
    "node-sass": "4.12.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-intersection-observer": "^8.32.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "17.0.15",
    "eslint": "7.31.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "11.0.1",
    "typescript": "4.3.5"
  }
```

Env: Mac-OS Big Sur
Browser Chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if some block has `white-space: nowrap` and it overflows horizontally, producing this issue.

Answer (score 2):

This is a CSS issue - you might need to style the `__next` element and do this:

```css
#__next {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @leerob, i had to remove flex-direction and min-height for this to work, i also had to add a media query for this to work properly

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem i fixed by adding this CSS style:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  #__next {
    display: flex
  }
}
```

I added a media query because if you set display to flex directly it will work but it will create the same problem on higher screens.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this meta tag inside your <Head /> in _document.tsx file

```
<meta
    name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
```

```
import { Head, Html, Main, NextScript } from "next/document";

export default function Document() {
  return (
    <Html>
      <Head>
        <meta
          name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no"
        />
      </Head>
      <body>
        <Main />
        <NextScript />
      </body>
    </Html>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried both styles, and actually, they only work when they are together:

```js
#__next {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
  min-width: 100vh;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  #__next {
    display: flex
  }
}
```

this is a weird bug that I have only had when deploying to Vercel, I have never had this issue when using NextJs on another server

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the problem was that I had some flex row components doing some unwanted overflow to the right, so I had to make them 'wrap' (jump to next line when they run out of space), by adding this to each of them:

```
flex-wrap: wrap;
```

If you're using Tailwind like me it will look like this on your component:

```
className="flex-wrap"
```